# Is it possible to combine the ggplot legend with the plotly legend so they are equivalent?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

I'm trying to combine ggplot and plotly together to make a timeline.

It's working great, but have an issue using the legend. The code below replicates what I'm trying to do.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
x=1:10
df2 = data.frame(x,y = 2*x+rnorm(length(x)),lab = as.factor(c("col1","col2")))
status_colors <- c("#0070C0", "#00B050", "#FFC000", "#C00000","darkgreen","purple","darkgrey","blue","salmon","darkorange","black","navy","darkblue")
status_levels <- c(sort(unique(df2$lab))) 

p= ggplot(df2,aes(x=x, y=y, col = lab)) + geom_point() + labs(col="labtest") +
  scale_color_manual(values=status_colors,
                     labels=status_levels, drop = FALSE)

fig = ggplotly(p, tooltip = NULL)

fig %>%  
  add_text(
    x = df2$x,
    y = ifelse(df2$y>0,df2$y+0.05,df2$y-0.05),
    text = df2$lab,
    hovertext = df2$lab,
    hoverinfo = 'text',
    mode ="text",
    textfont = list(color=status_colors[df2$lab], size =10),
    marker = list(color=status_colors[df2$lab], size = 0.00001),
    showlegend = T,
    textposition = ifelse(df2$y>0,"top center","bottom center")
  )
```

Basically, as you can see in the image, the label of each point is the same colour as the point that it is attached to. But whenever I add the legend of the label text from plotly, there is a new legend that appears that controls all the points regardless of their colour.

[image]

Thus, is there a way to combine the ggplot legend with the plotly legend so that it's only written col1 and col2 with the right colour and that whenever I interact with the points of a certain colour, the label attached to it stays there?

In other words, is there a way to remove the "`trace 2`" legend and make the "`add_text`" know that there is a legend already created in ggplot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got you right, besides getting rid of the second legend (which can be simply achievd by setting `showlegend = FALSE`) you want one legend to control both the points and the labels. This can be achieved via `legendgroup`s. Instead of adding labels with one `add_text` you could (or have to? Sorry. Still a plotly newbie so perhaps there is a simpler approach) add the labels via two `add_text` calls one for each `col`. Instead of copy and paste (which is probably okay for just two cols, but with more cols ...) you can add these via the magic of `purrr::reduce` to the `ggplotly` object. Try this:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
library(purrr)

x=1:10
df2 = data.frame(x,y = 2*x+rnorm(length(x)),lab = as.factor(c("col1","col2")))
status_colors <- c("#0070C0", "#00B050", "#FFC000", "#C00000","darkgreen","purple","darkgrey","blue","salmon","darkorange","black","navy","darkblue")
status_levels <- c(sort(unique(df2$lab))) 

p= ggplot(df2,aes(x=x, y=y, col = lab)) + geom_point() + 
  labs(col="labtest") +
  scale_color_manual(values=status_colors,
                     labels=status_levels, drop = FALSE)

fig = ggplotly(p, tooltip = NULL)

purrr::reduce(c("col1", "col2"), ~ .x %>% add_text(
    data = filter(df2, lab == .y),
    x = ~x,
    y = ~ifelse(y > 0, y + 0.05, y-0.05),
    text = ~lab,
    hovertext = ~lab,
    hoverinfo = 'text',
    mode ="text",
    textfont = list(color= ~status_colors[lab], size =10),
    marker = list(color= ~status_colors[lab], size = 0.00001),
    showlegend = FALSE,
    textposition = ~ifelse(y>0, "top center","bottom center"),
    legendgroup = .y
  ), .init = fig)
```

BTW: I also simplified the code a little bit. You don't need `df2$...` because `(gg)plotly` already knows the data.

[image]